# Making an event post expire AFTER event end time

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have the following code:

```
<?php

global $post;

$date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'snbp_event_date', true );

$newDate = date("M<\b\\r><\\s\\t\\r\\o\\n\\g>d</\\s\\t\\r\\o\\n\\g><\b\\r>Y", strtotime($date));

$nowdate = date('M<\b\\r><\\s\\t\\r\\o\\n\\g>d</\\s\\t\\r\\o\\n\\g><\b\\r>Y');

$now = date("M-d-Y", strtotime($date));
$then = date("M-d-Y");
$then2 = strtotime($then);

$exp_date = $date;
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d");

$today = strtotime($todays_date);
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);

echo $newDate

?>
```

I'm trying to make it so the theme sends an event to `past-events` AFTER the event's end time.

Currently the time is saved in the following function `snbp_event_time` and is in the following format `9:00 am - 11:00 am`

It seems that as it sits - the events convert to `past-events` before the event itself has ended. I'm trying to edit the function so that the current event adds the `past-event` type AFTER it ends - rather than during the event.

Note -- events typically run from 10p-3a and that's why I think they're 'expiring' before the end time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This code doesn't do anything other than display a date... you're creating a lot of variables with different dates but not doing anything with them. Can you show us the code where it gets converted to a `past-event`, you are actually checking for if the event is over, etc, so we can actually see whats happening and we might be able to help :) See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess that’s truly the problem; I’m not sure where to locate where that’s being done. I can’t seem to locate it myself among the code.